# get the edited values of an inputs filled by ng-repeat | Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

In my view, the user double click on a row and the details will pop up with input have been filled up by ng-repeat, the user could change the values, but my problem is that i can't get the new value of the input.

My view:

```
/* This dislay the inputs with the value, ng-dblclick will get the input values*/
<tr ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacture" ng-dblclick="editFacture();" >
    <td><input class="cls" value="{{sf.fcls_crt}}"  type="text"/></td>
    <td><input class="piece" value="{{sf.fpiece}}" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input class="cls_gate" value="{{sf.fcls_crt_gate}}" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input class="piece_gate" value="{{sf.fpiece_gate}}" type="text"/></td>
    <td><input class="note" value="{{sf.note}}" type="text"/></td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
// This function gets the **edited** values by input' class
$scope.editFacture=function(){

    var editedQuanCls=$(".cls").val();
    var editedQuan_piece=$(".piece").val();
    var editedQuan_cls_crt_gate=$(".cls_gate").val();
    var editedQuan_piece_gate=$(".piece_gate").val();
    var editedNote=$(".oNote").val();
    var editedNote_gate=$(".note").val();
    alert(editedQuanCls + " - " + editedQuan_piece + " - " + editedQuan_cls_crt_gate  + " - " + editedQuan_piece_gate + " - "+ editedNote + " " + editedNote_gate);

 }
```

My problem is that the function is only returning the values of the first **tr** in the ng-repeat, what should i add to get all values? many thanks in advance[image: When i double click, i expect to get the values of all rows, but what happens is that only values of first row are getting]

Comment: why can't you use `ng-model` on your input fields?

Comment: Stop using jQuery for things that angular does much simpler. Shouldn't be using dom code in controllers

Comment: please can you give me example ? i am very new to angular js and this is my first angular project, i tried to add ng-model but the values of the input changed to the value of ng-model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have refactored your code.

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myController',function($scope){

  $scope.selectedFacture = [{}];
  $scope.editFacture=function(sf){
    sf = sf || {};
    var editedQuanCls= sf.fcls_crt,
    editedQuan_piece= sf.fpiece,
    editedQuan_cls_crt_gate= sf.fcls_crt_gate,
    editedQuan_piece_gate= sf.fpiece_gate,
    editedNote= sf.note;
    alert(editedQuanCls + " - " + editedQuan_piece + " - " + editedQuan_cls_crt_gate  + " - " + editedQuan_piece_gate + " - "+ editedNote);
  }

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div ng-controller="myController">
   <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacture">
     <td><input class="fcls_crt" ng-model="sf.fcls_crt" type="text"/></td>
     <td><input class="fpiece" ng-model="sf.fpiece" type="text"/></td>
     <td><input class="fcls_crt_gate" ng-model="sf.fcls_crt_gate" type="text"/></td>
     <td><input class="fpiece_gate" ng-model="sf.fpiece_gate" type="text"/></td>
     <td><input class="note" ng-model="sf.note" type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" ng-click="editFacture(sf);"/></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you loading angular 1.2.23 here? That's really old and has deprecated things in it.

Comment: @MikeFeltman StackOverflow's Snippets allow you to automatically insert relevant scripts such as AngularJS. Their highest version is only 1.2.23, which is good enough to run the Snippet for testing purposes

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know. That really needs to be updated though.

Answer (score 1):

Pass sf into your function like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="sf in selectedFacture" ng-dblclick="editFacture(sf);" >
    <td><input class="fcls_crt" ng-model="sf.fcls_crt" type="text"/ </td>
```

Add it as a param to your function, then reference the properties via the parameter in your function.

```
$scope.editFacture=function(){
    var editedQuanCls=sf.fcls_crt;
    ...
}
```

Also, see this question: ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542)

Comment: wait i changed the value of the input fields, but it doesn't work! i want to get the new value, this is getting me the old values!

Comment: Yes, I actually missed that you were setting value by hand. You need to use ng-model as well to bind properly.

Comment: Updated to reflect that.